# How to use a variable in a regex pattern used in a GitLab CI if statement?

Tags: regex, gitlab

I am trying to use a variable in a CI GitLab if statement that uses regex.

How can I get it to use the variable `$CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME`?

This works:

`if: $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /(?:^|\W)automated patch version upgrade for dev(?:$|\W)/`

But if I replace "dev" with the `$CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME` variable which is assigned "dev" it does not work:

`if: $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /(?:^|\W)automated patch version upgrade for $CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME(?:$|\W)/`

Comment: I also tried using ${CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME} but it did not work.